# Edit a config variable of a custom module in controller

Tags: configuration, page-controller

Is it possible to edit/create a config variable of a module in a controller created in the same module?

For example:
module_name/src/Controller/MyController.php:

```
class MyController extends ControllerBase {

    public function x($y) {
        $config = \Drupal::config('module_name.settings');
        $config->set('var1', $y)->save();
    }
}
```

**Update**:

module_name.module:

```
function module_name_page_attachments(array &$page) {
  $config = \Drupal::config('module_name.settings');
  var_dump($config->get('var1'));
}
```

module_name/config/install/module_name.settings.yml:

```
var1: 0
```

module_name/src/Form/moduleNameSettings.php:

```
class moduleNameSettings extends ConfigFormBase {

    protected function getEditableConfigNames() {
        return [
            'module_name.settings',
        ];
    }


    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
        $config = \Drupal::config('module_name.settings');

        $this->config('module_name.settings')
            ->set('var1', $config->get('var1'))
            ->save();
    }
```

Comment: I'd say: Sure! Have you tried it already?

Comment: yes I did but it doesn't work I still can't get the new value of "var1" in module_name.module file! (Note: calling the controller is fine no problem with controller invoke)

Comment: In the submitForm method you seem to be setting the variable to its existing value rather than updating it.

Comment: I think that's the way to update it! what should I do instead?

Comment: See `ExampleSettingsForm::submitForm()` from [_Working with Configuration Forms_](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/working-with-configuration-forms).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the ConfigFormBase, you need to implement the editableConfigNames() method.  E.g.

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function getEditableConfigNames() {
    return [
      'example.settings',
    ];
  }
```

In general, you need to get the editable version of the config file to change it.  ConfigFormBase (well actually, ConfigFormBaseTraits) will only return the editable config is you implement the above method.

For reference, here's how you could do this without the ConfForm logic.

```
$config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('example.settings');
$config->set('message', 'Hi')->save();
```

See the [documents](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/defining-and-using-your-own-configuration-in-drupal-8) for details.

Since you are expanding ConfigFormBase, you should be able to use:

```
$config = $this->configFactory()->getEditable('example.settings');
```

To get the editable version.

Comment: IIUC they're already relying on the base class and using [`ConfigFormBaseTrait::config()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21ConfigFormBaseTrait.php/function/ConfigFormBaseTrait%3A%3Aconfig) (which does return the editable settings, assuming `getEditableConfigNames()` is set up correctly, which it seems to be).

Comment: D'oh.. look at my own code first.. editing answer.

Comment: `getEditableConfigNames()` has already implemented I just didn't mention it in the question trying to focus on `submitForm()` method.., and it works for me I use `$config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('example.settings');
$config->set('message', 'Hi')->save();` in the controller body. thank's a lot! :)